# My button is centered, even when I put in text-align: left;

Tags: html, css

I made a little start-up for a computer science project. 
For this project, we have to build just a regular website with HTML, CSS and if wanted, javascript.
I got my navigator menu thing from w3-schools but after putting the button in the top-container instead of the header, it suddenly centered instead of showing up left.

I deleted the `text-align: center;` from the top-container and put in `button {
text-align: left;
}`

Didn't work

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
    <div id="main">
        <section class="top-container">
            <h2>Just some bullshit here</h2>
            <button 
                id="openNav" 
                class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" 
                onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;
            </button>
        </section>
```

CSS

```
.top-container {
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   padding: 30px;
}

button{
  text-align: left
}
```

I expect the button being on the left side instead of being in the centre.

(here's a link to the whole code https://jsfiddle.net/Ellefien12/qg6thu5v/1/, I don't know why, but it is working in there, but when I have it in NetBeans 11, it isn't working)

Here's how it looks in firefox

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your button inside the div

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button id="openNav" class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" 
onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</button>
</div>
```

And then position the element

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: left;
}

#openNav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```